# Elasticsearch 5.x Full text regexp

Tags: elasticsearch

New to ELK, trying the full text search with regex, I create a test indice

```
  {"test_monitoring":
    {"aliases":{}
    ,"mappings":
      {"messagerie":
        {"properties":
          {"header":
            {"type":"text"
             ,"fields":
              {"keyword":
                {"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256
     } } } } } }
    ,"settings":
      { "index":
        { "creation_date":"1490005518469","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"f8AsV6OrQEqx7_-HoEYxwA","version":
          { "created":"5020299"}
        ,"provided_name":"test_monitoring"
  } } } }
```

so property "header"  is :

- text
- keyword

allowing normaly full text search and not only token with score

Putting 1 record into (data after get is)

```
hits|total                      | 1
    |max_score                  | 1.0
    |0|_index                   | "test_monitoring"
    | |_type                    | "messagerie"
    | |_id                      | "1"
    | |_score                   | 1.0
    | |_source|header           | "La pomme d adan n est pas utile a la mastication"
```

I can search with success via a:

```
"query": { "match": {
      "header" : "pomme"
      }    }
```

or  `"header.keywork" : "La pomme d adan n est pas utile a la mastication"`

but never a regexp with more than 1 word hit something [no error, full _shard, ...]  (ok for header.keyword but header is a text "not_analyzed" understanding the new ELK version [New text/string/keyword behavior](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)

```
GET /test_monitoring/messagerie/_search
{  "query":  {
        "regexp" :{
            "header" : "la.*pom*e"
}   }   }   }
```

I see lot of question about full text that show that the "not_analyzed" seems teh key to full text so I try to add a mapping of this type forcing a *not_analyzed* text attributes

```
PUT /test_monitoring/messagerie/_mapping
{
"messagerie": {
  "properties": {
    "header": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
          }
        , "as_text_na" : {
          "type" : "text"
          , "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but failed also with this new entry on this indice

The root question is:

what is missing for a full text regexp query on attributes *header* allowing to query a mulmti word data value where order of word is important ? Without order of word a boolean query should be enough, heavy but working.